# Swift/Objective-C Facebook SDK retrieving user data?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

Facebook include no swift help in their Docs, just objective-c. This makes it hard to understand what to do when using say the Graph API.

The following objective-c code is supposed to get some user information:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
        startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
        }
    }];
}
```

Could anyone explain how this would be done in swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translated the code to Swift :

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Fetched user : \(result)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's right but wrong too, "if error != nil" means there is an error. so should be "error == nil" then get the data, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zouvv Yeah ahah I did this a bit too quick I fixed it ;)

Comment: @Fanattitude I really appreciate your help, one more question. What exactly is supposed to be in the "parameters" part of the graph request if not nil? when is it used because the FB docs use it in some examples

Comment: @Zouvv `parameters` waits for a dictionary of type Dictionary<String, String>, it's not necessarily useful. Facebook documentation doesn't seem to specify potential things you could pass but it's logical since the method can be used to make any request.

Comment: @Fanattitude so you don't really have to use it, it can be nil for a lot of the time and the request will still take place wether its getting or posting data?

Comment: @Zouvv Yes, that's it. It will be used when posting data, you'll need to pass a dictionary with key/values corresponding to the parameters of the request.

Comment: thank you very much for that, great explanation and answers, i truly appreciate it. helped me a lot! have a nice day :)